# EF Core, batch get with IDbContextFactory performance

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following endpoint

```cs
[HttpPost("export")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Person>>> CreateCSV([FromBody] Request request)
{
    var t = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    List<AppDbContext> dbContexts = new List<AppDbContext>();
    List<Task<List<Person>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<Person>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < request.ContextCount; i++) dbContexts.Add(_dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext());

    List<int> batches = request.Count
        .Batch(request.Count / request.ContextCount)
        .ToList();

    for (int page = 1; page < batches.Count() + 1; ++page)
    {
        tasks.Add(dbContexts[page - 1].Persons

                        .OrderBy(entry => entry.FirstName)

            .AsNoTracking()
            .Skip((page - 1) * (batches[page - 1]))
            .Take(batches[page - 1])
            .ToListAsync());
    }

    var data = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).SelectMany(list => list);

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.AppendLine("Id, FirstName, LastName, SecurrityCode");

    Parallel.ForEach(
        source: data.AsParallel().AsOrdered(),
        parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
        },
        body: (entry) =>
        {
            builder.AppendLine($"{entry.Id}, {entry.FirstName}, {entry.LastName}, {entry.SecurrityCode}");
        });
    t.Stop();

    var seconds = t.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000d; 

    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), "text/xlsx", "users.xlsx");
}
```

What I want to do is query the same datasource and get the items in batches (if you have a better approch please make the suggestions)

What I've noticed is if I'm using orderBy as seen in the exemply, the more dbContext are created (e.g. 10) the more the time of computation increases as oposit to if I'm not using sorting the more dbContexts I have the better the performance.

I'm not sure why is this and what can I do to improve it.

Comment: Why you have created this? Single query is what should be effective. You have just increased load on the SQL Server.

Comment: Use single query, single context and No Parallel. It will be more effective than executing N requests.